# Python cx_Oracle in Heroku

Tags: python, oracle, heroku

I'm struggling with this for one week. I'm trying to run a python flask app that connect with a remote Oracle Database using instant client version 11.2.0.3.0.

After a lot of problems, I ended using 3 buildpacks, two of them I need to customize and then I could install cx_Oracle in Heroku, but when I run the code I got the error:

```
import cx_Oracle
ImportError: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Well, this error is very well documented, so I just needed to do:

```
$ apt-get install libaio1 libaio-dev
```

But the problem is how to run apt-get in a Heroku App? Using the third buildpack:

```
github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
```

The other buildpacks:

```
github.com/Maethorin/oracle-heroku-buildpack
github.com/Maethorin/heroku-buildpack-python
```

After everything is configured, I runned a Heroku deploy and got the same error on execution. I could see in Heroku deploy log that `heroku-buildpack-apt` did its job but I got the same error in `import cx_Oracle`. Btw, just to be sure, I changed the forked python buildpack, that I'm using, to do `pip uninstall cx_Oracle` at each deploy so I can have a freshly compiled version of it.

At this point, the Great Internet was not able to help me anymore. Anywhere that I looked, I got the option to install libaio. I tried to search about using apt-get in Heroku App but everything points to `heroku-buildpack-apt`

I think the problem could be cx_Oracle cannot find the installed libaio and I setted a lot of Heroku App environment variables:

```
$ heroku config:set ORACLE_HOME=/app/vendor/oracle_instantclient/instantclient_11_2
$ heroku config:set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/app/vendor/oracle_instantclient/instantclient_11_2:/app/vendor/oracle_instantclient/instantclient_11_2/sdk:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib:/lib
$ heroku config:set LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/app/vendor/oracle_instantclient/instantclient_11_2:/app/vendor/oracle_instantclient/instantclient_11_2/sdk:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib:/lib
$ heroku config:set INCLUDE_PATH=/app/.apt/usr/include
$ heroku config:set PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/app/.apt/usr/bin
$ heroku config:set PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
$ heroku config:set CPPPATH=/app/.apt/usr/include
$ heroku config:set CPATH=/app/.apt/usr/include
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention this:

When I run a `heroku run ls -la /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` where the libaio should be installed I got this:

```
drwx------ 3 u32473 dyno  4096 Dec 21  2013 .
drwx------ 3 u32473 dyno  4096 Dec 21  2013 ..
-rw------- 1 u32473 dyno 16160 May  9  2013 libaio.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u32473 dyno    37 May  9  2013 libaio.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1.0.1
drwx------ 2 u32473 dyno  4096 May 17 16:57 pkgconfig
```

But when I run `heroku run ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1.0.1` there is no file there. So the real problem is where are libaio installed?

Anyone can help me make this work? Or there is another good substitution for cx_Oracle?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to verify that libaio was actually installed into one of the directories in your LD_LIBRAY_PATH?

Comment: I forgot to mention that... I will edit my question... ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this... the problem was really the location of the `libaio.so`.

I started to look for all possibles places where this lib could be installed. I found it in `/app/.apt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and not in `/app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, where `heroku-buildpack-apt` think it was installed, nor in any of the system lib folders.

So I added this path in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and everything works fine!

Ty All!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with the same problems and fixed it after putting some efforts. I am sharing here the steps for hosting python flask app which connects external Oracle Database:

- cd {ProjectDir}
- pip install cx_Oracle
- pip install gunicorn
- Make file with name Procfile and put following in it: web: gunicorn yourapp:app --log-file=-  //yourapp is your flask python file
- pip freeze > requirements.txt
- git init
- create heroku
- heroku buildpacks:add heroku/python
- heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/featurist/oracle-client-buildpack
- heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
- heroku config:set BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES=1 //This is for shapely python package 
  (Optional)
- create file with name Aptfile and put libaio1 in it
- git push heroku master

Answer (score -1):

set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME and try again

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is already being set. And DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is only used by OS X, isn't it?

Comment: yes, thats only for MAC OS, for linux that would be LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: I already set ORACLE_HOME too: `heroku config:set ORACLE_HOME=/app/vendor/oracle_instantclient/instantclient_11_2` Add this to the question.

Comment: Setting environment variables to Oracle directories isn't going to help resolve the dependency on the system libaio library.